# I am not able to pass the parameter in the link to function

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-router

I was working on front-end using ReactJS. I was trying to send the parameter I got from the link to function by using :
        `<Route path="/dta/:pid" component={this.DtaDisplay}/>`
. I am not able to a use the parameter in the DtaDisplay() method. Can anyone help me?

```
render() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>      
    <div>
    {this.NavigationDta()}
    <p className="App-intro">
      <Route path="/dta/:pid" component={this.DtaDisplay}/>
      <Route path="/rrf" component={this.ReferenceRangeFactorDisplay}/>
    </p>
    <p className="App-intro">
      <Route path="/nomen" component={this.NomenDisplay}/>
    </p>
    </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

```
DtaDisplay = () => {
    return <h1>{pid}</h1>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use parameters like this:

```
<Route path="/dta/:pid" component={this.DtaDisplay}/>
```

```
DtaDisplay = ({match}) => {
    return <h1>{match.params.pid}</h1>
}
```

Refer to this docs from [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

Comment: You'r welcome! If you review the documentation of React Router, you will find more useful recipes. ;)

Comment: How can i store the value in a variable , say,     const value={match.params.pid}. this is not working. how can i solve it?@Yulio Aleman Jimenez

Comment: Just without use the brackets Eg: `const value=match.params.pid`. The brackets in your case is only to show or use the value of `pid` as rendered value.

Answer (score 1):

The component which is rendered through the `Route` recieve the Router props. Amongst these you can access the query params using the `match.params.pid`

```
DtaDisplay = (props) => {
    const { match: { params: { pid }}} = props;
    return <h1>{pid}</h1>
}
```

Using the above you can use `pid` at other places necessary without having to write `props.match.params.pid` repetitively.

Comment: This solution is interesting, and more convenient when to want to use `props` values more than few times. +1.